# Confirm a tag or category is associated with page or post - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tags, categories

Can you see a **post's** category or tag by inspecting the code in browser?

I ask because I installed a plugin to add **categories** and **tags** to my **PAGES**, but even though there is UI for it in the dashboard, I can't tell if it's actually applying a category or tag to said pages, and want to be sure. 
Trying to eliminate variables.
My queries/args to sort pages by category or tag never do anything, and have tried several methods.

this is my code right now:

```
<?php

$args = array( 

'post_type' => 'page',

'child_of' => 6,

'taxonomy' => 'tag',

'field' => 'slug',

 'term' => '2017'

);

$pages = get_pages($args);

?>
```

in order to get pages that are children of page with ID '6' but I want only the 'tag' OR category, I dont care, '2017'. I can list the right children, but the sorting of cat/tag never happens. Using a plugin to add categories and tags to pages.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a plugin to do this. Add this code to your functions.php

```
function add_tags_to_page() {  
    // Add tag metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page'); 
    // Add category metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_tags_to_page' );
```

Add this to your page.php somewhere to test that the tags have been saved to the post. You can remove it afterwards or use it to output them onto the page.

```
echo var_dump(get_the_tags());
```